# How to kill the session in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I m working on login module. In logout function i worte the code as below, first kill the session,then redirect it to home page. It is working fine but session is not destroying.
If anybody knows please help me
Here is my code snippet for login & logout:

```
function login()
{

   if(!empty($this->data))
    { 

       $user1= $this->User->validateLogin($this->data['User']);

         if($user1== true)
        {

               $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
                $this->Session->setflash('Login failed, Try again'); 
         }
    }
}

function logout()
{

    $this->Session->delete('User');
    $this->redirect('/users/index');
}
```

I got information that, I have to keep header information, below is my code snippet:
$this->header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); $this->header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");

But m not getting in which part of my controller i should paste this code? Please help me....

Comment: if you are using auth(cakephp sessin variable you don not need to delete session mannually....I think you missed this part

Answer (score 8):

Try $this->Session->destroy();
The destroy method will delete the session cookie and all session data stored in the temporary file system. check this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Sessions.html#destroy)

Comment: thank you samir.... Even I checked with destroy also, But my problem is, if i click 'back' button of browser, it will shows all login history...

Comment: @pushpa :- try destroying cookie also.I hope this work.           Write after session destro $this->Cookie->destroy();

Comment: Also in logout function write $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

Comment: I have not used auth in my loginform. SO Auth->logout() is not working.and $this->Cookie->destroy(); will give Undefined property error

Comment: @ samir:                                                              I am using cakephp1.2 , do i need to modify any configuration file?

Comment: "if i click 'back' button of browser, it will shows all login history"- this is a cache problem of the browser - not of your application

Comment: If you press F5 (ie. refresh/reload) after pressing back, you should see that what you were looking at was a cached version of that page (as @mark points out) and that you are indeed logged out. You need to tell the various browsers out there that the page a) must not be cached, b) must not be stored persistently, c) must be revalidated by asking the server, d) has expired. Setting the following in your controller (or AppController) should cover this: `$this->header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); $this->header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting redirected because it's not allowed, not because of the redirect in your logout function. You need to allow the use of the logout function too, in the beforefilter of your controller (CakePHP 2):

```
$this->allow('logout');
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont want to kill the session. only to log the user out!

```
$this->Session->delete('Auth');
```

otherwise you destroy cookies and other user defined settings which would be pretty annoying (language, ...)

but the official cake way would be:

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```